# Chow lemma for complex spaces

Tags: complex-geometry, cv.complex-variables

Is there something like the Chow lemma for complex spaces (stating that every compact complex space is birational to a projective variety, or some variant of this, like: every proper morphism of complex spaces is birational to a projective morphism)?

Comment: For projective spaces, the transcendence degree of the field of meromorphic functions is equal to the dimension. For arbitrary compact analytic spaces, it can be smaller. So asking for a birational map is too much.

Comment: Just a nitpick: it's probably better to say "projective variety" rather than "projective space"; by convention the latter really means some $\mathbf{P}^n$.

Comment: And every (proper) morphism of projective varieties is in fact projective.

Comment: @ArtiePrendergast-Smith: Thank you. That was what I meant of course.

Comment: @JérômePoineau: just to clarify, my comment was really meant for the OP, not you!

Comment: @ulrich: I meant "complex spaces", not "projective spaces".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, if a complex compact manifold $X$ of dimension $n$ is bimeromorphic to a projective variety, its field of meromorphic functions must have transcendence degree $n$ (the maximum possible) -- one says that $X$ is a *Moisezon manifold*. Conversely, a deep theorem of Moisezon asserts that any compact Moisezon manifold  becomes projective after a finite number of blowing ups with smooth centers.